# Next always returns a new value even though revalidate is set

Tags: next.js, next.js13

The following code block doesn't work as expected. I keep pressing refresh and get the time back every time, even within 10 seconds. Why? If I change the whole thing to cache:'no-store', the behavior is the same, which is also desirable in this case.

app/layout.tsx:

```
import Loading from "./loading";

type Time = {
  datetime: string;
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const res = await fetch(
    "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin",
    { next: { revalidate: 10 } }
  );

  const data: Time = await res.json();
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="flex h-full flex-col">
        <p className="font-bold text-3xl text-center mt-32">{data.datetime}</p>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```